# How to make Regex in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, regex

I'm always confused with Regex format how they work and how to make Regex according to my requirement. I just copy some common Regex formats and paste in my project but obviously we cant find every Regex format according to our requirement. So i would like to learn about Regex.

I make it just from my guess after run code again and again but still i dont know so much about this Regex

```
NSString *regexNumber = @"[123456789][0-9]{0}([0-9]{1})?";
```

This compare `Age`, according to this age should be start from 1-9, minimum 1 digit, maximum 2 digits and numeric only.

Now i want to make Regex for **Name -** (exp - vakul, Vakul, vakul saini, Vakul Saini, vakul Saini, Vakul saini etc.), **Email**, **Phone Number**, **String Only**, **Birthday**, **URL**.
But dont want to copy and paste i want to learn how they work and how to make my own Regex.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A regular expression is a text pattern consisting of a combination of alphanumeric characters and special characters known as metacharacters

The metacharacters are:

```
\ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ? . < >
```

`.`  ---- It is instead a special metacharacter which matches any character.

`*`  ---- The * character matches zero or more occurrences of the character in a row.

`+`  ---- The + character is similar to `*` but matches one or more.

`?`  ---- Zero or one instance of characters

`{m,n}` ---- means match m or up to n characters. eg `{1,5}` matches 1 or upto 5 characters

`^` ---- it would match any line which began with the word following it

`$` --- it would match any line which ends with the word following it

`<>` --- matches words between them. Eg.  returns all words that contain abc

You can form groups, or subexpressions as they are frequently called, by using the begin and end parenthesis characters: 
`()` The ( starts the subexpression and the ) ends it

`|` --- Or Parameter

`[ and ]` --- Sequence of characters. Any characters put inside the sequence brackets are treated as literal characters, even metacharacters. The only special characters are - which denotes character ranges, and ^ which is used to negate a sequence. eg. `[a-z]`

This is the most basic knowledge you need for regular expressions and they are same for almost all languages.

For further details you can refer [this link](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Regex.html)

Comment: iOS is using a modified version of ICU 4.2.1 lib. The API docs are located at http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/index.html

Comment: I already mentioned `This is the most basic knowledge you need for regular expressions and they are same for almost all languages.` And these do work in ios as well, almost all

Comment: Happy to help :) U can accept it if it helped you..

Answer (score 0):

you should use [Regexkit Framework](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net), i found it the best solution for regex in iOS

Comment: Thanks @iYaniv - would it teach me how to make Regex ??? I dont want to copy others Regex because no one can give me every Regex format what i need. So i want to learn to make my own....

Comment: go to http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth have already given that link see first comment of this question..... It is good link to learn..